# border-bottom missing on each page ending row in a table when exporting to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, html-table, winnovative

I have tried so many ways to get back the bottom-border of the row which was the last row in every page break. The style is added to each  is **border:1px solid #000;** but if I give **2px** instead of **1px** it will show the border. And the border is **border-collapse: collapse;**
I am using Winnovative for PDF export.

1. border:1px solid #000;

[image]

2. border:2px solid #000;

[image]

Please help me to fix.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add a  with border-top to make a line on the last line. The footer is repeated on every page

Answer (score 0):

**you can wrap into the another table**

```
content: [
        {
          table: {
            widths:["100%"],
            body:[[ {
              table: { }, // replace your table here
            },]]
          },
          layout: {
            hLineWidth: function (i, node) {
                return (i === node.table.body.length) ? 1 : 0;
            },
            vLineWidth: function (i, node) {
                return 0;
            },
            paddingLeft: function (i, node) {
              return 0;
            },
            paddingRight: function (i, node) {
              return 0;
            },
            paddingTop: function (i, node) {
              return 0;
            },
            paddingBottom: function (i, node) {
              return 1;
            },
          }
        },
      ],
```